# bcp utility delimiter not accepting different parameters

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to load a file using SQLServer BCP Utility and here is my script,

```
bcp DB.dbo.table_1 in c:/TABLE_1.txt -t | -c -S username\SQLEXPRESS -T
```

For some reason if the delimieter is a vertical pipe symbol it does not accept it,

Here is the error,

```
'-c' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I don't have problems using a comma delimiter but my data itself will have commas.

Comment: `|` is used at a prompt to 'pipe' commands from one to another. Your interpreter thinks that you are trying to run a program called `-c` which of course doesn't exist. You may need to put quotes around the `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the | symbol and it should work.

`bcp DB.dbo.table_1 in c:/TABLE_1.txt -t"|" -c -S username\SQLEXPRESS -T`